# Get values from an Array and calc

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an array width this values:

```
array: (
    {
    id = 1;
    name = "Cursus Nibh Venenatis";
    value = "875.24";
},
    {
    id = 2;
    name = "Elit Fusce";
    value = "254.02";
},
    {
    id = 3;
    name = "Bibendum Ornare";
    value = "123.42";
},
    {
    id = 4;
    name = "Lorme Ipsim";
    value = "586.24";
}
)
```

What I need to do is get each 'value' and sum it all. Im declaring a new array to take each value:

```
self.valuesArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

But how can I do it? Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double sum = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"] doubleValue];
```

You can read more on collection operators [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: Does this enumerates all array?

Answer (score 1):

You have already declared array so i will use your. I also assume your first array(which contains data set above) is an array called `myFirstArray`(of type NSArray)

```
    int sum =0;
    self.valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for(NSDictionary *obj in myFirstArray){
      NSString *value =[obj objectForKey:@"value"];
      sum+= [value intValue];
      [self.valuesArray arrayWithObject:value];//this line creates a new NSArray instance which conains array of 'values'(from your dictionary)
   }

    NSLog("The sum of values is: %d", sum);
    NSLog("The array of \'values\' is : %@",self.valuesArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double sum=0.0;

for (YourDataObject *d in array) {
    sum+=[[d getValue] doubleValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
 float totalValue = 0.0f;

 for (int i = 0 ; i< [array count]; i++) {
     totalValue +=[[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
}
```